# How can I make sure that a rounding error doesn't happen when I multiply a number, round it, then pull it back out?

Tags: rounding, rounding-error

We have this API that we need to make payments to. On our side we have an initial payment and a fee of 3% that we add to get the total. 
We take this and pass it to the API which then pulls it apart. It knows about the 3% fee and breaks it down to the fee and the payment by takeing the total amount and multipling by  97.09% to get  the payment.
The problem we are having is that the API only excepts to 2 decimals places but we need things to work out to the penny.
So for example:

```
payment: $100.01
makes fee of $3.0103
total = payment + fee = 103.0103 (rounded to 103.01)
reverseEngineered = total * percent = 103.01 * .9709
leaves us with 100.012409 (100.01)
```

Which is correct but for this example

```
payment = $333.33
makes fee of 9.9999
total = payment + fee = 343.3299 (rounded to 343.33)
reverseEngineered = total * percent = 343.33 * .9709
leaves us with 333.339097 (333.34) 
333.33 != 333.34 so there is a problem when rounding.
```

I don't control the API otherwise I would have the percent be more accurate (97.08737864%).

Any ideas on how this can be done or is there no way to ensure it returns witout rounding errors.

After doing some math i found that using %2.99721907 as the fee percentage make more numbers work out

```
{
    Though process x*y = z therefor z / y = x;
    x / .9709 = z therefor z *  .9709 = x
    1 / .9709 = 1.299721907
}
```

Example

```
payment = $333.33
makes fee of 9.9906303260
total = payment + fee = 343.3206 (rounded to 343.32)
reverseEngineered = total * percent = 343.32 * .9709
leaves us with 333.329388 (333.33)
```

But I'm not sure this will always be the case. Does anyone know a way I could be sure? Or will this not work for every number?

**Edit:**

I'm going to be more clear about the standing with the API. We didn't write/ don't have control over the API. A company we are working with do. We might be able to suggest changes but nothing more that that.

When we send the payment over the API on the other companies end they are breaking the payment and fee apart and sending the funds to two separate accounts. This is why the fee needs to be reverse engineered

Answer (score 0):

Since 97.08737864 does not equal 97.09, you're screwed. Why are you using an API for such a simple calculation?

Comment: It's a payment processing API. On the other end of things it's splitting up the total payment to send the fee and payment to to different acccounts

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I think you know by now, it will never work-you need to change the api. You can't redefine math.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing this out in php/Laravel. Dumping the starting payment and the final result to the log files along with the overall difference between the original payment and the final result payment. This is the code I used for testing.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

    public function run(){
        set_time_limit(300000);
        for ($payment = 330; $payment < 340; $payment += .01) {
            //Fix the weird increment problem with floats
            $payment = round($payment,2);
            $fee = $this->applyFee($payment);
            $total = $fee + $payment;
            $returned = $this->passToAPI($total,true,false);
            // \Log::alert($payment . ": " . ($returned["Payment"] - $payment));
            \Log::alert($payment .": " . round($returned["Payment"],2));
            \Log::alert($payment - $returned["Payment"]);

            if($payment != round($returned["Payment"],2)){
                \Log::alert($payment . " is unequal");
            }
        }
    }

    public function passToAPI($value, $round = true, $roundResult = true){
        $rndTotal = $round ? round($value,2) : $value;
        $Payment = $this->reverseEngineerPayment($rndTotal); 
        $Fee = $rndTotal - $Payment;
        $Payment = $roundResult ? round($Payment,2) : $Payment;
        $Fee = $roundResult ? round($Fee,2) : $Fee;
        return  array("Payment" => $Payment, "Fee" => $Fee);
    }

    public function reverseEngineerPayment($total){
        return $total * .9709;
    }
    public function applyFee($payment){
        return $payment * .0299721907;
    }

    public function reverseEngineerFee($total){
        return $total * .0291;
    }
}
```

When using .03 for the applyFee function the results were somthing like this

```
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330: 330.01  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: -0.0089099999999576  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330 is unequal  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.01: 330.02  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: -0.0086190000000101  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.01 is unequal
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.02: 330.03  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: -0.0083280000000059  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.02 is unequal  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.03: 330.04  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: -0.0080370000000016  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.03 is unequal  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.04: 330.05  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: -0.0077459999999974  
[2018-07-12 13:47:10] local.ALERT: 330.04 is unequal
...
```

Which was kind of expected because of the calculation rounding error.

But when I used
.0299721907 for the applyFee function the results were like this

```
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 330: 330  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 0.00079900000002908  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 330.01: 330.01  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 0.0010900000000333  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 330.02: 330.02  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 0.0013809999999808  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 330.03: 330.03  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 0.001671999999985  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 330.04: 330.04  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 0.0019630000000461  
[2018-07-12 13:50:21] local.ALERT: 330.05: 330.05
```

They always returned to the penny the result I passed in. It seems like the rounding error only goes up the the decimal after the penny making it so the results are always the desired results.
Note* I also tested this script from 1 to 50,000. and was unable to find any instances where the result wasn't the same.

I realize this is pretty clunky but it works as far as I can tell. If you can find a reason that this wouldn't work out then I'll be happy to not use it, but as far as I can tell it's solid.